# PyGTK, wxPython or Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, wxpython, pygtk

I'm starting to develop interfaces for my python applications , but I've seen that there are diferents tools to do it, so I would like to know which could be the best,  I need something, easy, portable and pretty results. I hope that you can help me.

Comment: Then there's also [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro) and [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/)...

Comment: wxPython, pyGTK, PyQT they all are similar level of easeness, probably similar level of portablness too. wxPython used native UI. tkinter is not full featured gui library.

Comment: Could this question be unmarked as a duplicate? The question that it has been marked as a duplicate of has been deleted / moved.

Answer (score 1):

Pick the one you like, there's no "the best" here.

Personally I like PyQt4, because I like QT4, and py2exe works perfectly fine with it, wxPython is another good thing, but it does not work very well under Windows, see my question here: [wx.App (wxPython) crash when calling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369102/wx-app-wxpython-crash-when-calling)

You can check some application developed using each frameworks, and see if you like any.

Comment: `wxPython` (or the newer version `wxPhoenix`) is nearly a dead project. Only one maintainer who is not willing to accept other contributors or to document his stuff. Bugs for years and far behind the original wxWidgets.

Answer (score 1):

For PyGTK - [Glade](http://www.pygtk.org/articles/pygtk-glade-gui/Creating_a_GUI_using_PyGTK_and_Glade.htm) should be your best bet. Similarly, [Rapyd-Tk](http://www.bitflipper.ca/rapyd/) seems to be good for TK. Though for Tk, I would advise you to try with the articles which help you build from the code and then go with the builders. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800849/nice-ide-for-wxpython-or-tkinter-gui-development) in SO provides the wealth of options available for building GUI using WxPython.